# Display loading screen while Web View Component load page in app inventor

Tags: javascript, android

Am new in App inventor. Am developing an APP in APP Inventor and i want a screen that will Display loading or progress while Web View Component load page and fetch the data from url for display. Normally it show white blank while loading so i want to replace it Loading Screen so that user will know the page is loading in the App

Please help,. Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the issue on your own means? People here are generally very helpful, but you do have to show some effort by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your activity's xml a progress bar and set its visibility to false 
then in your activity or fragment class when its fetching the data:

mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

after its done fetching data use the same line but set it to invisible.